# How to Access SAS Server with IOM Protocol in R

Tags: r, server, sas

I'm trying to read in SAS data into R similarly to this quick tutorial here: https://josezea.wordpress.com/2019/05/02/connect-sas-server-from-r/

The issue is that the server I'm trying to connect to uses an IOM protocol, which doesn't seem to be supported in the `RCurl` package. Does anyone have any suggestions to reading data from a SAS Server with these protocols in R? It can be reading from a file pathway or a library, either works for my scenario. Thanks!

Below is the code I attempted to run in R:

```
library(RCurl)
library(haven)

protocol <- "IOM"
server <- "server.com:5555"
userpwd <- "username:password"
sasfileRoute <- "/path_to_data/bonus_schedule.sas7bdat"

## Read Data as data frame

url <- paste0(protocol, "://", server, sasfileRoute)
binary_sasdata <- getBinaryURL(url = url, userpwd=userpwd)
df_data =  read_sas(binary_sasdata)
```

Comment: Have you tried using the R2SAS package in R? https://mran.microsoft.com/posts/r2sas

Comment: Is this a SAS9 server or a SAS Viya server?

Comment: It is a SAS9 server

Answer (score 3):

I think you're misunderstanding what the linked page does.  It shows how to use R to read in a SAS dataset - but not to connect to SAS.

SAS datasets are usually stored as .sas7bdat files.  You should connect via SFTP or network share or similar to access datasets; this won't work if the datasets are stored in a LASR server or other in-memory location of course.

If you need to connect to SAS itself (to execute code or to access in-memory data), you can do so if the SAS server is a SAS Viya server.  See [R SWAT](https://github.com/sassoftware/R-swat) for more information on that; it uses SAS's APIs to do what you need.

Otherwise, you will have to run the SAS executable from inside R (if you have access to that version of SAS), or have a SAS user export your data for you from inside SAS.  I am not familiar with a way to connect to SAS 9 via R directly, and the link in comments seems out of date (CRAN at least doesn't seem to have that package any more).

SASPy does allow Python to do something similar with SAS 9.4, so perhaps that's a better route if you have SAS 9.4.

Comment: It's funny you mention SASpy, as I have been trying to get the configurations for that put together. I was just hoping that something similar had been built out for R, and to be honest I'm a bit shocked that there hasn't been.

Comment: SASPy was developed by SAS itself - not that someone couldn’t develop something similar but it is somewhat complicated I suppose. One of my coworkers wrote a Java executable for windows to do the same thing.  I think the issue is you have to basically develop all of the routines - you don’t want to just develop a pass through connection because that doesn’t add enough.

Comment: That makes sense, if you look into the SASPy GitHub page it does seem fairly dense. In case anyone's interested they also seem to be taking examples and recommendations at the saspy-examples GitHub found here: https://github.com/sassoftware/saspy-examples

Since we brought all this up I thought it may be useful to share

Answer (score 0):

IOM is a SAS protocol used by its Integration Technologies product. Instead of IOM, find the network path to the file and use it. See resources using IOM (C#, Java, PowerShell, etc.) on the SAS website. Usually, IOM is used for code submission and SAS object management.